Can reed relays be measured with multimeter?
I have some G3MB-202P relays.
These are for to be operated from standard 5V. With multimeter when they are on they just change from about 330 ohm to 270 ohm.
If I do an experiment having a regular LED connected through it then after the relay is closed the LED stays on. Why?
Are these for AC applications only or what's wrong with them?

The question title mentions a reed relay, yet the G3MB-202P datasheet indicates a Solid State Relay. Can you clarify what type of rely is in use?

Where did the idea that this is a reed relay come from?

Those are not reed relays but SSRs and why the LED stays on is unknown as you don't give any info how you drive them in what kind of circuit, so you likely just use them wrong in a wrong circuit. Edit: oh right it's not a relay but a triac which explains it.

The G3MB-202P is a triac type SSR so it won't turn off until the current through it drops below a certain level (maybe a few mA).
So it's rated for, and generally only useful for, AC applications. Of course you're free to use it in a DC application if that 'latching' characteristic might be useful- but I don't see the holding current specified so that might be hard to do reliably.
For example, you could have it turn on an alarm light and the light would stay illuminated until the circuit is broken (or the SSR output is shorted by a switch). The holding current (to stay 'on') and maximum dv/dt (to keep it from spuriously turning 'on') are a couple important characteristics in that use case.
